# WCF List Data Member

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF API which needs to return a Json response like this:

```
  {
      "Status":"ERR",
      "Errors":[
           {"Code":"Err_Auth_NoInfo"}
           "Message":"There has been an error with the settings of this website. Please         contact us as soon as possible to get your issue resolved"
        ]
    }
```

My DataContract:

```
 [DataContract]
 public class Response
 {        
     [DataMember(Order = 0, IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
     public List<error> Errors { get; set; }
 }
 public class error
 {
     [DataMember]
     public string Code { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
     public string Message { get; set; }
 }
```

How will I have to form a class to return data in my method? I tried it

```
 Response info = new Response();
 error e = new error();
 e.Code = "test code";
 e.Message = "test message";
 info.Errors = new List<error>();
```

But this isn't working.

Comment: I think JSON and XML works in REST services. But you can change your response in JSON string and then return it.

Comment: What bindings are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your `Response` object doesn't have a property `Status`, you should add it:

```
[DataContract]
public class Response
{
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public string Status { get; set; }        

    [DataMember(Order = 1, IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public List<Error> Errors { get; set; }
}
```

Secondly your `Error` class is missing the `[DataContract]` attribute, you should also add it:

```
[DataContract]
public class Error
....
```

Now you can create your `Response` like this:

```
Error e = new Error
{
    Code = "Test code",
    Message = "Test Message"
};
Response response = new Response
{
    Status = "ERR",
    Errors = new List<Error> { e }
};
return response;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Response
{        
    [DataMember(Order = 0, IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public List<error> Errors { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return js.Serialize(this);
    }
}
```

**JavaScriptSerializer** is available in **System.Web.Script.Serialization** class.

In your Service implementation method implementation, do this: Change the return type to **string** and call these lines.

```
//Your code here.
return myResponse.ToString();
```